# Error 1054 MYSQL Workbench Forward Engineering

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench

Can't understand how to solve this problem, thought it was because `` but it's not.

ERROR: `Error 1054: Unknown column 'departure_airport' in 'field list'`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `RedWingsDatabase`.`Route` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `departure_airport` VARCHAR(205) NULL,
  `destination_airport` VARCHAR(205) NULL,
  `flight_duration` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

USE `RedWingsDatabase`;
INSERT INTO `RedWingsDatabase`.`Route` (`id`, `departure_airport`, `destination_airport`, `flight_duration`) VALUES (1, 'Москва, Домодедово', 'Владивосток, Кневичи', 510);
INSERT INTO `RedWingsDatabase`.`Route` (`id`, `departure_airport`, `destination_airport`, `flight_duration`) VALUES (2, 'Воронеж, Пётр I', 'Омск, Центральный', 210);
INSERT INTO `RedWingsDatabase`.`Route` (`id`, `departure_airport`, `destination_airport`, `flight_duration`) VALUES (3, 'Самара, Курумоч', 'Москва, Домодедово', 105);
INSERT INTO `RedWingsDatabase`.`Route` (`id`, `departure_airport`, `destination_airport`, `flight_duration`) VALUES (4, 'Санкт-Петербург, Пулково', 'Москва, Домодедово', 90);
```

Comment: This works in db<>fiddle:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=49686a951bda49eb268358e01b1cb86b.

Answer (score 0):

For multi-byte characters use `NVARCHAR`

Try:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Route` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `departure_airport` NVARCHAR(205) NULL,
  `destination_airport` NVARCHAR(205) NULL,
  `flight_duration` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
```

Edit : [Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eDu7HRRZ8eXJ79W4gvEUNb/0)

Comment: How does that matter in this situation? How would using a `varchar` cause a syntax error?

Comment: @underscore_d Check this demo https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eDu7HRRZ8eXJ79W4gvEUNb/0

Comment: If try to use `VARCHAR` I am getting error `Schema Error: Error: ER_TRUNCATED_WRONG_VALUE_FOR_FIELD: Incorrect string value: '\xD0\x9C\xD0\xBE\xD1\x81...' for column 'departure_airport' at row 1`

Comment: Right, but that's a very different error from the one the OP got. Either they quoted something else, or they have an extra problem.

Comment: @DigvijayS Nope, still have this problem.

Comment: I will add that the error occurs exactly in INSERT INTO